# Loading Emulator take forever

Tags: android-studio

When i running my first hello world in android studio but the emulator load like forever I am using Asus Tuf Dash F15 a very strong laptop can  anyone help me?[image: And it take forever]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pc meets the requirements to run the emulator, but you should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator) to see if you can make it run faster.
Also I advice you to run your apps on a phisical android phone if you have one, it's easier and the emulator is kinda heavy.

Comment: Moreover, the user experience is really different with a mouse than with your finger on a touchscreen, a physical device is really the best way to test your code if you have one